# How to solve publishing a state update that happens before a client subscribed

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, publish-subscribe, tsx

So I'm exploring a new framework I made which can be used to write React / TSX components on the backend.

I'm implementing a few basic examples showing how hooks can be used to hook into the lifecycle of components.

The issue arises when implementing a view counter using the `useClientEffect` hook.

Suppose the following server side component

```
export const ViewCounter = (props, { key, initiator }: RenderOptions) => {
    const [views, setViews] = useState(0, {
        key: 'views',
        scope: Scopes.Global,
    });
    const [clients, setClients] = useState(0, {
        key: 'clients',
        scope: Scopes.Global,
    });

    useClientEffect(() => {
        if (initiator !== Initiator.RenderClient) return;
        setClients(clients + 1);
    }, []);

    useClientEffect(() => {
        if (initiator !== Initiator.RenderClient) return;
        setViews(views + 1);
    });

    return (
        <ServerSideProps key={`${key}-props`} views={views} clients={clients} />
    );
};
```

The `useClientEffect` is called each time a component is rendered on the server in the context of a connected client. It's like `useEffect` on the frontend, but is called on the server side when a server component is consumed / rendered on the client side.

The component / issue can be seen live at https://state-less.cloud

When the page is loaded and the ViewCounter component is rendered on the client side, then the callback passed to `useClientEffect` is being called which increases the counter by one. This in turn causes a re render of the component where it publishes the updated state to all *subscribed* clients.

However, the client doesn't yet have subscribed to changes because the re render on the serverside happens before the client can send it's subscription to the component.

That is because I don't know the PubSub subscription key without rendering the component. I cannot pre compute it because components may have dynamically computed keys.

This leads to the issue that a client that loads the page receives an outdated state because it doesn't receive any updates to the component it just rendered.

[image]

In the picture you see that the count is 10, but it's actually eleven on the server. Now suppose a second user opens the same page and the counter is increased by one again.

This leads to the counter jumping by 2 instead of increasing by one because it now receives the actual live value as it subscribed to changes of the component.

[image]
So the problem is that the currently connecting client is a state update behind whereas all prior connected clients receive the updated state.

**How can I solve that in a clean way?**

I suppose I could somehow record the state updates of the last few seconds and transmit them to a newly subscribing client if I can figure out if he received it.

But that makes the whole thing a bit too managed. If there are a lot of state updates it also increases memory usage.

I'm sure this is already solved, I just don't know the proper way to handle it.

Comment: If someone else has any good ideas, just post an answer, I will award the bounty to one.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to provide another lifecycle event that get's executed once the client subscribed to any updates.

Instead of calling the `useClientEffect` once, you call it multiple times for different lifecycle events. Call it again when the component mounts on the client side and move the `setViews` call to the lifecycle event that get's executed once the client subscribed to changes.